# Add data from second 2d array to first 2d array based on related id columns

Tags: php, arrays, mapping, merging-data

I have two arrays $a and $b

```
$a = [
    '0' => [
        'name'=>'Apple',
        'id' => 1
    ],
    '1' => [
        'name'=>'Banana',
        'id' => 2
    ],
    '2' => [
        'name' => 'orange',
        'id' => 3
    ]
];
```

AND

```
$b = [
    '0' => [
        'price'=> 20,
        'a_id' => 2
    ],
    '1' => [
        'price'=> 10,
        'a_id' => 3
    ],
    '3' => [
        'price'=> 30,
        'a_id' => 1
    ]
];
```

I am trying to create another array with mapping with id(array $a), a_id (array $b), where my output will looks like:

```
$a = [
    '0' => [
        'id' => 1
        'name'=>'Apple',
        'price' => 30
    ],
    '1' => [
        'id' => 2
        'name'=>'Banana',
        'price' => 20
    ],
    '2' => [
         'id' => 3
         'name' => 'orange',
         'price' => 10
    ]
];
```

I have tried by array map

```
$combined = array_map(null,$a,$b);
```

But this result is not my desire result. How can I map my 1st array with 2nd array related by `$a['id'] = $b['a_id']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, also if there's no price for an item in the array $b then the default price 0 will be added.

```
<?php

$result = [];

$t = array_column($b, 'a_id');

foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    
    $index = array_search($v['id'], $t);
    $v['price'] = $index !== FALSE ? $b[$index]['price'] : 0;
    $result[] = $v;

}

print_r($result);

?>
```

**Result:**

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Apple
            [id] => 1
            [price] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Banana
            [id] => 2
            [price] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => orange
            [id] => 3
            [price] => 10
        )
)
```

Comment: I am confused here for array_search in loop ? Is it efficient ?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't matter in micro-environments !!

Comment: Another problem is if I have another array element in array $a , then it getting wrong price. Example I added 
'4' => [
        'name' => 'charry',
        'id' => 4
 ] in $a array , then charry will get price 20.

Comment: @RezaulZablu edited my answer, please check :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```php
foreach($a as $k => $item)
{        
    $price = 0;    

    foreach($b as $priceItem)
    {
       if($priceItem['a_id'] === $item['id'])
       {
            $price = $priceItem['price'];
            break;
       }   
    }

    $a[$k]['price'] = $price;
}
```

However, this isn't too efficient as every new price and item will exponentially increase the loops required.

If you are able to use the product IDs as the key in your first array, you could do it a lot more efficiently:

```php
// Key $a by product ID
$a = [
    1 => [
        'name'=>'Apple',
        'id' => 1
    ],
    2 => [
        'name'=>'Banana',
        'id' => 2
    ],
    3 => [
        'name' => 'orange',
        'id' => 3
    ]
];

foreach($b as $priceItem)
{   
    $a[$priceItem['a_id']]['price'] = $priceItem['price'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
$result = [];

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($a); $i++){
    if(array_key_exists($i,$b)){
        $b[$i]['id']=$b[$i]['a_id'];
        unset($b[$i]['a_id']);
    }
    $result[] = array_merge($a[$i], array_key_exists($i,$b)?$b[$i]:array());
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: If I increase array $a element, this solution making error.My array $a element can be increase and it can be grater then array $b.

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is more efficient, but maybe a bit more flexible, and readable.
Its on you!

```
<?php

$a = [
    '0' => ['name'=>'Apple', 'id' => 1],
    '1' => ['name'=>'Banana', 'id' => 2],
    '2' => ['name' => 'orange', 'id' => 3],
    '3' => ['name' => 'extra', 'id' => 4]
];
$b = [
    '0' => ['price'=> 20, 'a_id' => 2],
    '1' => ['price'=> 10, 'a_id' => 3],
    '3' => ['price'=> 30, 'a_id' => 1]
];

$lookup = [];
foreach($b as $k => $v) {
    if (array_key_exists($v['a_id'], $lookup)) {
        // you have multiple prices... do something, throw an error, log an error, overwrite the value
        // what ever you want
    } else {
        // in case you have multiple array items you want to copy over
        // you can later merge the array
        // if its only ever going to be prices , you can just take the price instead of the unset
        $parent_id = $v['a_id'];
        unset($v['a_id']);
        $lookup[$parent_id] = $v;
    }
}

// in case you have more values that you want push, if nothing exists
$default_values = ['price' => 0];

foreach($a as $k => &$v) {

    if (array_key_exists($v['id'], $lookup)) {
        $v = array_merge($v, $lookup[$v['id']]);
    } else {
        $v = array_merge($v, $default_values);
    }

} 
/* bit less readable
foreach($a as $k => &$v)
    $v = array_merge($v, array_key_exists($v['id'], $lookup) ? $lookup[$v['id']] : $default_values);
*/
print_r($a);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Apple [id] => 1 [price] => 30
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => Banana [id] => 2 [price] => 20
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [name] => orange [id] => 3 [price] => 10
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [name] => extra [id] => 4 [price] => 0
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to avoid nested `array_search()` calls, this will not be the most efficient approach.  This task should be completed with a On on each array; in other words, do not iterate either of the arrays more than once if you want the best possible time complexity.

1. Use `array_column()` with a `null` 2nd parameter to temporarily assign `id` values as first level keys -- this will make relating the two arrays very easy and efficient.
2. My snippet below will use "array destructuring" to unpack the `$b` data and push `price` elements into the result set.
3. When the loop is finished, use `array_values()` to re-index the output array (if you wish).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nXhVG))

```
$result = array_column($a, null, 'id');
foreach ($b  as ['a_id' => $a_id, 'price' => $result[$a_id]['price']]);
var_export(array_values($result));
```

It's just that easy/simple.